# How can I improve this super easy-basic-newbie-like code?

Tags: java

Though this program works, I'm not sure it's the best way to compare user choice to three values x, y, z. What else could be possible?

```
  if (userchoice == 1) {

        double x = p1.getStorageSize();
        double y = p2.getStorageSize();
        double z = p3.getStorageSize();

        System.out.println("How much memory do you need?");
        double memoryByUser = input.nextDouble();

        if (memoryByUser > x) {
            ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList <>();
            numbers.add(p1.getModel());
            if (memoryByUser > y) {
                numbers.add(p2.getModel());
            } else {
                print = numbers;
            }
            if (memoryByUser > z) {
                numbers.add(p3.getModel());
                print = numbers;
            } else {
                print = numbers;

            }

        }

    }
    return String.valueOf(print);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Yup seems strange, but you can definately move the code print=numbers out of if-else blocks and use it only once. In fact, move the the numbers declaration out of the if block and directly use String.valueOf(numbers)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Not in it's current form. This is way too snippety for Code Review. It would work if a bit more context is provided and a lot more of the code is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing a variable to three values can be done in different ways. It would be interesting to know if it is safe to make any assumptions about the relation of the three values (for example x >= y >= z). Your code is comparing your variable to y and z ONLY IF the value of the variable is larger than x; otherwise y and z are not touched.

Besides thinking about the logic of the three values, you can tidy your code a little bit. This is a condensed version which avoids unnecessary declarations and assignments of variables.

```
if (userchoice == 1) {
    ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("How much memory do you need?");
    double memoryByUser = input.nextDouble();

    if (memoryByUser > p1.getStorageSize()) {
        numbers.add(p1.getModel());
        if (memoryByUser > p2.getStorageSize()) {
            numbers.add(p2.getModel());
        }
        if (memoryByUser > p3.getStorageSize()) {
            numbers.add(p3.getModel());
        }
    }
}    
return String.valueOf(numbers);
```